# Get url from javascript onclick element in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to get href url from `onclick` javascript function.

This is my button element:

```
<button class="module_bnt" onclick="window.location.href='https://someurl.org/module/'">  Click Here to Start Quiz</button>`
```

This is my parsing function:

```
def parse(self, response):
    articles = response.xpath('//article')
    for article in articles:
        id = article.xpath('./@id').get()

        if id is not None:
            id = id.encode('utf-8') # converting to utf-8 and removing u character space in string
                
            moduleBnt = article.xpath('.//button[@class="module_bnt"]/a/@href').get()

            if moduleBnt is None:
                moduleBnt = article.xpath(".//button[@class="module_bnt"]/a/@onclick").extract_first()
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `onclick` attribute value using css selector and then use regex to extract the url.

Something like this:

```
url = response.css('.module_bnt::attr(onclick)').re('href='(.*)')[0]
```

Comment: re('href='(.*)') , Here it has 3 quotation marks, could you please correct it